# Is there an error in this code because it outputs the success message correctly but nothing gets updated in the database

Tags: php, pdo

Below is my code:

```
$sql1 = "Update Exams set   
            Institution_Level=:level,
            ExamYear=:year,
            ExamTerm=:term,
            ClassName=:cls,
            Subject=:subj,
            ExamType=:etype,
            ExamAndAnswersPdf=:pdffile,
            ExamPreview=:epreview,
            ExamAndAnswersDoc=:docfile,
            Description=:des,
            Uploaded_On=:date,
            Price=:pr 
        where IdExam=:id";

$smt = $conn->prepare($sql1);
//execute the query
if ($smt->execute(['level' =>$lev, 
                    'year' =>$Eyear, 
                    'term' =>$term, 
                    'cls' =>$class,
                    'subj' =>$subject, 
                    'etype' =>$type, 
                    'pdffile' =>$fileName, 
                    'epreview' =>$filePreview, 
                    'docfile' =>$fileworddoc, 
                    'des' =>$desc,
                    'date'=>$date, 
                    'pr' =>$prc, 
                    'id' =>$exid])) 
{
    # code...
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Exam Edited SuccessFully";
    header("location:UploadExam.php");
    exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['err'] = "Sorry!! Exam could not be updated";
    header("location:UploadExam.php");
    exit;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The query is probably sound but it's not matching the id that's in `$exid`. Double-check the value and make sure that value exists for IdExam in the database.

Comment: It exists. Am updating the record as per the ExamId passed via a url parameter. redirecting the the session message like above without passing the same id to  the location can it affect? and when I try to pass the same id to the header location it appears null like : /UploadExam.php?ExamId=

Comment: How can I pass the Same exam Id to the header location of the success message?

Comment: This is how am passing it:  header("location:UploadExam.php?ExamId=".$exid);

Comment: If it's null in the URL, it's not being passed correctly. You'll want to check the file with the header code and troubleshoot why it's not being passed along

Comment: Thanks. I was using IdExam passed via url to update database. I got it working using a session instead.